# Javascript Switch usage in function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my javascript function which replaces "yyyy" of a date format with "yy" and replaces "yy" with "y"
example

```
    validateDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy") gives "dd/mm/yy"
    validateDateFormat("dd/mm/yy") gives "dd/mm/y"
```

Here is my js function

```
function validateDateFormat(format) { 
    var index =  format.indexOf("yyyy");    
    if(index <0 )
     {    var index =  format.indexOf("yy");    
          if(index <0 )
             return format;
          else
               return format = format.substring(0, index) + format.substring(index+1);          
     }
    else 
        return format = format.substring(0, index) + format.substring(index+2);
}
```

Am trying to re-write the function with switch or make it recursive, is it doable?

Comment: Have you tried the alternatives? how did that turn out?

Comment: Am a novice js programmer, I tried using switch but its not doing what i intended to

Comment: I think you can replace your entire function with `return str.replace(/yy/g, 'y');`: http://jsfiddle.net/mQQdx/. There may be a few edge cases...

Comment: @JasonP Hmm, what a nonsense function. I guess it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess You want something like this?

```
function validateDateFormat(s)
{
    if(s.indexOf('yyyy') > -1)
      return s.replace('yyyy','yy');

    return s.replace('yy','y');
}

alert(validateDateFormat('dd/mm/yyyy')); // "dd/mm/yy"
alert(validateDateFormat('dd/mm/yy')); // "dd/mm/y"
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ds4ek/)